# The purpose of interfaces continued

Tags: java, oop, interface

OK so I gather that Interfaces are a way to enforce that an object implements a certain amount of functionality, without having to use inheritance. Kind of like a contract. And I semi see the point of them.

But if all you have in the interface is:

```
 public interface animal{
  void eat(object food);
}
```

and it has no implementation as such, then whoever uses your interface has to write it from scratch, every time.

If you are creating a number of classes all implementing such features and the implementation is only slightly different, this is going to be a lot of hard work.

Any help to get my head around this is appreciated because I know it's really important.

Comment: Sorry about my awful 'typos' Carl just clicked the button without really reading it thoroughly. Lot on my mind it seems. Cringe-worthy stuff when you look at the mistakes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24436493/1286942

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Interfaces are the only way to create multiple inheritance in Java.

Say you create a class `Animal`. And all animals, including humans extend that. And each of those animals inherits common methods like eat, breathe, etc.

But now let's say you have a `MathProblem` class.
And you want to have certain classes that can solve that problem by passing the problem to a `solve(MathProblem problem)` method.
And you know that a `Human`, but also a `Computer` might solve the math problem. So they both need to be able to solve that problem. You might be able to get the Computer to extend some `MathSolver` class that has the method, but Human already extends Animal, and can't extends anything else. So a better way is to make MathSolver an interface and have both `Human`, `Computer`, and any other classes that need to solve problems implement that.

Also note that a `Human` and a `Computer` might solve the problems in completely different ways, since their such different objects. That's what interfaces are best for. Defining certain abilities that cut across multiple inheritance hierarchies, and can have very different implementations, but can all be passed to a method that accepts any of them. Think of the `Comparable` interface; it's not something a certain class of objects has, all sort of things can be compared, and usually in very different ways. But you can always call sort on a `List` of `Comparable` objects since you know they have a certain order, no matter if they're `Numbers`, `Animals`, `Computers` or anything else (as long as they implement `Comparable` and define their ordering).

Comment: +1 - I think it's important to add that there are two purposes of inheritance: (1) allow inherited-class objects to be used in place of base-class objects, and (2) allow inherited-class objects to make use of base-class behaviors.  Interfaces don't do anything useful toward the second purpose, but are very helpful toward the first.

Answer (score 4):

[Prefer Composition over Inheritance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)  This way, you can implement (say) eat() in a class that gets incorporated into all your animals as a data member.  Write it once, reuse it, but in a way that doesn't bind one kind of functionality explicitly to another.

If you had two (or ten) different ways of eating, you could swap them out as needed.

Comment: Although composition seems the best way to avoid code duplication in this particular case, this answer tends to make think that interfaces are useless in Java. Don't forget that there's also another design principle saying "program to interfaces, not concrete classes". So interfaces in Java are definitely something to understand and use almost everywhere.

Comment: Good point.  I just edited to add the "swapping out" bit, which I think may address it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing interfaces and inheritance. They are different concepts and can complement to each other. If all the eat methods are only slightly different, then you can create a base class which will contain the common code and will be invoked from the subclasses through overriden methods which add the different parts. The base class can still implement the interface. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Right, you need to implement it ever time but you can implement it differently every time and any class that calls it doesn't need to worry about how it's implemented.

For example, if you have a Zoo object with a bunch of animals (new Tiger(), Lion(), Bear()) then your zoo can do for each Animal a in some collection a.eat() and it will work.  The zoo doesn't care that there are three different types of animals that eat in totally different ways.

Answer (score 2):

> If you are creating a number of classes all implementing such features and the implementation is only slightly different, this is going to be a lot of hard work.

In that case you are easily allowed to create another layer in you hierarchy of classes which implements `Animal` but is an ancestor class for all animals that eat in some way, for example

```
class Herbivore implements Animal {
  public void eat(Object food) {
   ...
  }
}

class Cow extends Herbivore..
class Horse extends Herbivore..
```

and you are allowed to override `eat` by using `super.eat()` and changing only the slight part..

You should look forward code reuse and encapsulation of components at the same time.. then if your interface really doesn't characterize the class itself but just a component of it you can go by composition as suggested by Carl Manaster.

Answer (score 2):

You should think of an interface as an authoritative *declaration of behaviour*, which has nothing to do with implementation issues in the first place.

If you want to avoid code duplication, then you use an abstract base class in combination with the interface. Here you then can implement all the stuff that might be repeated in all interface-implementing classes otherwise.

HTH.
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

Using interfaces is more about giving the consuming code a way to know what you expect from it, rather than you needing to be concerned about the details of the consuming code.

For example, one of the ways we use interfaces a lot is in our Business Layer / Data Access Layer.

Because our business layer (BL) assembly will communicate with directly with the data access layer (DAL) assembly, the DAL cannot communicate directly with the BL.  What happens if the DAL wants to use objects rather than individual fields?  You would have to define your own DAL objects, and hydrate them with the input you've just received.  Basically, a lot more work, more resources consumed, and multiple objects that represent the same data which makes for a maintenance nightmare.

But, if you define interfaces in the DAL, you can tell consumers of the DAL what it expects.  Then you can implement those interfaces in the BL and pass instances of the interfaces instead of BL objects.

Interfaces are all about abstracting out the details of the implementation where they're not absolutely necessary.

[Edit]
If you have a lot of objects that do similar things, a combination of an interface and a base class with overridable/virtual methods might be more useful than just an interface.

Answer (score 1):

And old thread, I know. But I just read "Interfaces are the only way to create multiple inheritance in Java". This is very wrong, because delegation (or "compositon" as Carl said) is the only way to get multiple inheritance (remember: "delegation is inheritance", well, almost).

You only need interfaces to tell the developer "hey, don't forget to delegate this or that class"! Interfaces are only needed as reminder for a correct delegation (or in general: implementation), but they can't inherite any code. With multiple inheritance interfaces wouldn't be needed at all.

Actually, you don't really need interfaces to create a working program, they're just helpers without any function or functional code. Btw Thomas was very right with the abstract classes, these are far more important than interfaces, because that's where you can get reusable code from.

Normally, when I write a java application I only create interfaces in the very end, as a helper for future programmers. Or I don't create any interfaces at all ;D

Comment: Interfaces are not helpers.  They are not contracts to remind developers to implement methods.  Interfaces are to be coded against, so that you can decouple specific implementations from the places where the functionality is desired.

Answer (score 1):

One major reason is that you can create an object using an interface reference, similar to an abstract method.  When you do this, every object which implements the interface can be assigned to it.  For example, if `Dog` and `Car` both implement `Washable`, then you can do:

```
Washable wD=new Dog();

Washable wC=new Car();
```

If Washable has the public abstract method `wash()`, then you can do this:

```
wD.wash();

wC.wash();
```

and their respective methods will be called.  This also means that you can accept an interface as a parameter for a method meaning you don't have to add unecessary code to deal with every class which implements a certain interface.

See here for a more detailed explanation: http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/PolymorphismInterfaces1.html

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

**Generalization**

Using JAVA Interface we can achieve generalization across sub-class. The generalization means here sub-classes having same behavior implemented in a different way.

**Standardization**

Interface allows to set standardization for all the sub-classes which implements it. It specifies "what" the sub-classes must have but doesn't enforce how it should have.

**100 % Abstraction**

Interface body provides 100% abstraction, so that the sub-class should not miss any implementation of abstract method. This isn't possible if we use abstract classes.

**De-Coupling(Loose Coupling)**

While developing an application, the code which interacts with end users can be loosely coupled to the code running on the server[B L C] by using interfaces.

**Multiple Inheritance**

Using interfaces we can achieve MI which is not possible using classes.

Answer (score 0):

> and it has no implementation as such
>   then whoever uses your interface has
>   to write it from scratch..every time.

Each implementation of the interface can be different. The point is that you can use interface without knowing the implementation. Consider example:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void WriteMessage(string message);
}
```

Your application may use `ILogger` interface for logging errors/debug information, etc. But it doesn't matter how logger is implemented - it can be `FileSystemLogger`, or `DatabaseLogger`, or any other implementation. So you will be able to substitute implementations at any time without changing all places in code where logging was mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about it backwards.
Instead of thinking about the implementation first, you think about behavior (as described by the method signature) first. Then you implement the behavior as appropriate in the base classes giving a much more flexible, extensible system.
You dismissed "design by contract' pretty quickly, but it's  a key design strategy and the basis for web services, SOA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer so much as an example that I find helpful when thinking about interfaces, but think about the interface `Comparable<T>` which requires the method

```
public int compareTo(T anotherObject)
```

The user can implement this however he or she wants.  If a `Person implements Comparable<Person>`, for example, the comparison can be based on last name then first name, ignoring capitalization.  Or it can be based on age, etc.  However the user wants.  Implementing this interface is very useful, in that it allows the user to use things like `Collections.sort()` which require that the elements to be sorted need to be comparable (how else could a comparison be made?)